# Android Wear get GPS Coordinates

Tags: android, gps, location, wear-os, location-services

I'm unable to get a Location on my Android Wear Emulator. I've tried many tutorials but non worked and I don't understand whats wrong. Below is my sample source Code which is pretty similar to the original Android Demo from google.
 onLocationChanged never gets executed and when I try to retrieve the last Location I alway got NULL

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

public class MainActivity  extends Activity implements    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {


private TextView mTextView;
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS = 2000;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL_MS = 1000;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    });

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)


            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    System.out.println("Connect to Playservices...");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    System.out.println("onConnected");
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS)
            .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL_MS);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                        System.out.println("Successfully requested location updates"+status.getStatusMessage());

                    } else {
                        System.out.println(
                                "Failed in requesting location updates, "
                                        + "status code: "
                                        + status.getStatusCode() + ", message: " + status
                                        .getStatusMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}

public void getLocation(View view)
{
    Location loc=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(loc!=null) {
        System.out.println("Location: " + loc.getAltitude() + "\n" + loc.getProvider() + "\n" + loc.getLongitude());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Location null");
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    System.out.println("onConnectionSuspended(): connection to location client suspended");
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    System.out.println("onConnectionFailed(): connection to location client failed");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged (Location location)
{
    System.out.println("onLocationchanged: new location"+location.getAltitude());
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    System.out.println("onstop");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    System.out.println("onresume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    System.out.println("onPause");

}
}
```

Comment: I think you have added the location permission in manifest both on mobile manifest and app manifest right?

Comment: I have only one manifest AndroidManifest.xml and i have the following permissions:                                                                                           <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>\
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: I think the best way would be to send the GPS updates from mobile rather than having it on Watch..  you can have service running on mobile in background which will send the GPS co-ordinates to watch.